# Expanding recycler view items

Tags: android

I have gone through other questions as well but couldn't figure out something. I have a well set up RecyclerView.

[image]

I m trying this library: https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout

Now I want the items to be expandable so that they show a TextView which is different for each item.

But I can't figure out how to place itms in XML. Where to place RecyclerView and where the expandable layout? How to setup these things?

Comment: It'd be great if you could provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at one of the samples given in the library, it is called 'examplerecyclerview' which I think is the one you need.

These are specific files that you should watch:

- [RecyclerView Activity and Adapter (Java)](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/jp/android/aakira/sample/expandablelayout/examplerecyclerview)
- [RecyclerView Activity (XML)](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_recycler_view.xml)
- [RecyclerView List Row (XML)](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/recycler_view_list_row.xml)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Was putting the code in activity xml although it was to be placed inside RecyclerView ListRow. Now it's working